# How would you implement String to json object unmarshaller for parameter of url-encoded POST?

Tags: scala, spray

How would you implement String to json object unmarshaller for parameter of url-encoded POST ? I'm using version 1.2.

Here is what I want. Foursquare pushes url-encoded POST to my service. My route looks like this

```
  path("handle_4sq_push") {
    formFields("checkin".as[FsqCheckin], "user".as[String], "secret".as[String]) {
      (checkin, user, secret) =>
        complete {
          StatusCodes.OK
        }
    }
  }
```

I have json parser for `FsqCheckin` which is defined like this

```
  implicit val fsqCheckinFormat = jsonFormat(FsqCheckin.apply, "id", "createdAt", "timeZoneOffset", "user", "venue")
```

So it's all good but it works only if parameters are form-encoded. Otherwise Spray says

```
There was a problem with the requests Content-Type:
Field 'checkin' can only be read from 'multipart/form-data' form content
```

So I thought I'd write unmarshaller. I wrote this

```
  implicit def MyJsonUnmarshaller[T: RootJsonReader] =
    Unmarshaller.delegate[String, T](ContentTypes.`*`) {
      value => {
        val json = JsonParser(value)
        json.convertTo[T]
      }
    }
```

But if I bring it to scope of my route I get following compile error

```
too many arguments for method formFields: (fdm: spray.routing.directives.FieldDefMagnet)fdm.Out
        formFields("checkin".as[FsqCheckin], "user".as[String], "secret".as[String]) {
                  ^
```

It's the same error I have if I didn't have json parser for `FsqCheckin` in the scope.

How can I deal with this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shockingly I figured it out myself. Here is working version of universal unmarshaller.

```
implicit def String2JsonParser[T: RootJsonReader] = new FromStringDeserializer[T] {
  def apply(value: String) =
    try
      Right(JsonParser(value).convertTo[T])
    catch {
      case ex: Throwable => Left(spray.httpx.unmarshalling.MalformedContent(ex.getMessage))
    }
}
```